# RDF vocabulary extendability

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, vocabulary

I am new to RDF and I am unsure if I understand everything. As far as I know, a vocabulary like FOAF, DC, etc. provide predicates as well as objects.
So what is, if I want to create a vocabulary for cars were I provide objects representing brands so that users can make something like this:

.../#aCar a theCarOntology:Ford

If a new car producer comes to market, I have to update my ontology...
Are vocabularies appropriate for such things or do I have to write more generic vocabulaires without?

Kind regards

Comment: A vocabulary is just a set of URIs that you've decided to use with some particular meaning.  You can always decide later on that you want use some more URIs.

Comment: If you publish a definition of your vocabulary though, e.g., as an OWL ontology or RDF Schema, it might be useful to any applicable versioning features that you can get, so that people know things like "term X appeared in version 3."

Answer (score 0):

As I know, FOAF does not provide final objects like #BarackObama as instance of foaf:person

But Dublin Core, for example, have specific types as instances of dc:type (see https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-type-vocabulary/#terms-type for this property and https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/2012-06-14/?v=dcmitype#Collection as example of it's value). And yes, DC some times provide new version of his vocabulary, you can see this by my links

In other hand, any car trademarks and producers can have own IRI, and in same time can have yours IRI, and RDF allow anyone to have a dictionary of synonyms to recode incoming RDFs into recognisable IRIs of target processing system. You also can provide one of them.